# Auth Component redirects automatically in cakePHP

Tags: authentication, cakephp, components, redirect

After adding Auth component while accessing the home page it redirects to login page
ie., let www.domain.com is my url.
After adding the auth component when i try to access www.domain.com it redirects to www.domain.com/logins/login.

how can i avoid this initial redirection??

i already given a route as below

```
Router::connect('/', array(
    'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'
));
```

but no use
thankz in advance

Comment: when i try to use var $components = array('Auth'); in app_controller and skip that statement in pages_controller the "allowedActions" statements are not taking effect. iam using cakePHP 1.2. any body hav any idea where i am going wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In AppController::beforeFilter() add the following:](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1550/Setting-up-permissions)

```
$this->Auth->allowedActions = array('display');
```

UPDATE: `allowedActions` are controller actions for which user validation is not required.
http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-AuthComponent.html#228-234

Comment: Nb: will affect ALL pages. So you would need more if e.g. you still want some pages to be protected by Auth.

Comment: What do you mean by "all pages"?

Comment: If you're using the default `PagesController`, the `display` action handles multiple templates - e.g. `home.ctp` in your example above.

If you had other "pages" (aka. templates) controlled by the `PagesController`, (e.g. `about.ctp`) the above code fragment would also allow those to be viewed without authentication.

If that's what you intended, then great. Otherwise, you can alter `PagesController`, or use a different controller, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In your pages_controller.php (if you don't already have one in `app/controllers`, copy the one from `cake/libs/controller`:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
}
```

Comment: Do remember to change this back afterwards! Also don't get caught by allowing login and logout, as iirc they are available by default in the component. Check the book ideally :)

Comment: @DY: In the pages controller it shouldn't be an issue as it it there to display public pages that don't fit elsewhere. I should have checked the default - it actually has $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('display'); which should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just add this code to your `users` controller to stop it from automatically redirecting, but like everyone else said, you should also allow `display`.

```
function beforeFilter() {
    ...
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/395/autoRedirect

Comment: Sorry nick this is used to redirect after successful login right?
but thatz not my case